# Is there a way to recursivly set "Snap to Grid" as a folder setting in finder?

Tags: finder, terminal.app

macOS Catalina

I have noticed that when I create a directory it does not inherit "Snap to Grid".

Is there a way to make it that a folder inherits that setting or is there a command I can run to recursively set "Snap to Grid"?

Comment: In View Options, there should be a button that says "Make Default."

Comment: Okay, I was unaware of that, but do you know how to do that from the terminal?